# How Can we store C++ Class object as a value in Redis database?

Tags: c++, redis

Currently we wanted to use Redis as our in-memory database for Application and also we are new to Redis database. Could you please let us know how can we store a Class object as a value in Redis. We have tried by converting Class object to char buffer and then store into Redis Database as string. Then retrieve from Redis as a string and convert it to class object. What we saw, after converting the string (which has retrieved from Redis) to Class object is giving some junk values.

So, Could you please help us here.

Note : We used base64_encode and base64_decode to store into Redis and from Class object to char buffer, we have used memcpy/reinterpret_cast. Here the decoding and encoding is working fine without using Redis database. But once we use Redis database to store and then do decoding and encoding, then it's not working.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Redis doesn't modify your data. There might be some problem with your code. By the way, since Redis can save binary strings, there's no need to use base64 to encode and decode the data.

Comment: "We have tried by converting Class object to char buffer" <- I suspect this could be the issue - how did you perform the serialization (and then the "convert")?

Comment: @for_stack  and Itamar Habar, Thanks for your comments, Now we are able to store and retrieve  proper object by using char buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach with char buffers could in theory work with simple classes that do not allocate heap memory (given that you handle alignment issues).

Try using some serialization library like protobuf, boost::serialization, cereal etc instead.

Here is an example with [cereal](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/):

```
#include <cassert>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

#include <hiredis/hiredis.h>
#include <cereal/archives/binary.hpp>
#include <cereal/types/memory.hpp>
#include <cereal/types/unordered_map.hpp>

class foo {
    int i;
    std::string s;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> m;

    friend class cereal::access;

    template <typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& archive) {
        archive(i, s, m);
    }

public:
    foo() {}
    foo(int i, const std::string& s) : i(i), s(s) { m[s] = i; }

    friend bool operator==(const foo& l, const foo& r) {
        return l.i == r.i && l.s == r.s && l.m == r.m;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    cereal::BinaryOutputArchive archive{oss};
    foo f{10, "bar"};
    archive(f);

    auto redis_context = redisConnect("127.0.0.1", 6379);
    const auto set_reply =
        redisCommand(redis_context, "SET key %b", oss.str().c_str(), oss.str().length());
    freeReplyObject(set_reply);

    // later on
    const auto get_reply =
        static_cast<redisReply*>(redisCommand(redis_context, "GET key"));
    std::string repr{get_reply->str, static_cast<size_t>(get_reply->len)};
    freeReplyObject(get_reply);

    std::istringstream iss{repr};
    cereal::BinaryInputArchive input(iss);
    foo g;
    input(g);

    assert(f == g);

    redisFree(redis_context);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and nicely explained.